# How to disable loading message, when I use emacs to open a easycrypt *.ec file

Tags: init-file, message

[image]

I use Emacs GUI in Ubuntu, when I use Emacs to open a easycrypt file, for example `a.ec`, Emacs will show a loading message at the bottom of the window, I guess it is in the minibuffer, but I am not sure.  Could you please let me kown how to disable or modify this message? I have already [image]disabled message buffer, and put

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t
      initial-buffer-choice  nil)

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) 

(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

in my `~/.emacs` file, but the message still there when I open `.ec` files.

Comment: When I type `M-x describe-function` aka `C-h f` and look-up `load`, I see a `*Help*` buffer that states (in part):  `(load FILE &optional NOERROR NOMESSAGE NOSUFFIX MUST-SUFFIX)`  To the extent that you are using the function `load`, the second optional argument is `NOMESSAGE`.  E.g., `(load "/path/to/file" 'noerror 'nomessage)`  I would suggest trying to find out where you are loading `easycrypt.el` in your startup and see if you can modify the call to `load` as indicated in this comment.

Comment: ** How do I disable the splash screen?

Choose Proof-General > Customize Options and disable "Proof
Splash Enable" (at the bottom) and choose "Save for Future
Sessions" by clicking on the state button.

Alternatively, put this in your configuration file:

Comment: I use this to change the setting of my proofgeneral, and It works.

Comment: It's not the minibuffer, it's the echo area (but the minibuffer is indeed itself displayed in the echo area).  See section 1.2 of the manual for more info.